# How do I get an `Isolate` from a `Local<Object>` handle?

Tags: c++, v8

I don't have much knowledge of *V8*, but I know that [`Local<Object>`](http://bespin.cz/~ondras/html/classv8_1_1Local.html) is a *light-weight stack-allocated object handle* for an `Object`. How do I get an `Isolate` wherein a `Local<Object>`'s referee (the `Object` object) exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's intended to work the other way round: you start by creating the `Isolate`, then a `HandleScope`, then `Local`s in the latter. Just keep track of the `Isolate` you created, and use that when needed.

(For completeness' sake: for the time being, you can also get an `Object`'s `Isolate`, but that function is deprecated, so you shouldn't rely on it. Proactively thinking about which `Isolate` you want to use at any given point helps prevent nasty, subtle bugs.)

Comment: Hmm, so there's no non-deprecated way to obtain the `Isolate` from an `Object`. Unfortunately I'm not the one creates the `Isolate`. I'm working with _Node.js_ bindings in C++ and it seems to be not _providing_ the `Isolate` for the `Init` function, which is for initialization of a _Node.js_ module.